# Alternate for polling Kafka server

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any alternate for Kafka server polling for consumer/client (in KAFKA 0.10.0.0)?

```java
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));   
while (true) {  
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);  
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)  
        System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());  
 }
```

Comment: Why do you ask this question? Is polling raising any problems for you?

Comment: Actually my requirement is, to implement rest API for consumer. if it is continuously polling I could not able to get the message from consumer.

Comment: Why not using Confluent's REST proxy? https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest and http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/kafka-rest/docs/ and http://www.confluent.io/blog/a-comprehensive-open-source-rest-proxy-for-kafka/

Comment: Yes , that is my final option . In meanwhile am try to finding alternate solutions than confluent.io

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Brokers in Kafka are passive and clients need to pull data from there (a push model is not supported).

The poll loop example is recommended. See also http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/clients/consumer.html#java-client

Comment: But it is being deprecated.

Comment: The old `poll(long)` and the new `poll(Duration)` are basically the same, with slightly different blocking behavior (cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-266%3A+Fix+consumer+indefinite+blocking+behavior for full details). This change does not affect the answer to this question.